# Swift 5 App - AdMob returns Timeout (XCode)

Tags: ios, admob, swift5, xcode11.4

I want to show a Reward Ad (Google AdMob) in my swift app. (XCode 11.4, Swift 5, Storyboard), but whenever I load the ad it shows the following error message in the console:

```
Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=5 
"Request Error: The Google Ad request was unable to be fulfilled before a timeout occurred." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: The Google Ad request was unable to be fulfilled before a timeout occurred., gad_response_info=<GADResponseInfo: 0x6000030f8090>}
```

I basically followed the tutorial from [Google AdMob Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start).

1. I added my *GADApplicationIdentifier* to the `info.plist`
2. In the AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
}
```

3. In the ViewController I followed the steps from the new [RewardAd Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-ads) and basically copied and pasted it, except for replacing the AdId with my own (I'm running it in a Simulator, so using own AdID's should not be a problem if I understood correctly...)

This is where it fails:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: adId)

    rewardedAd?.load(GADRequest()) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error while loading ad: \(error.description)")
            // Timeout occurs here!!!
        } else {
            if self.rewardedAd?.isReady == true {
                self.rewardedAd?.present(fromRootViewController: self, delegate:self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Any idea why I get the timeout?**

*Note:*

- I also created a sample SwiftUI app with the same rewarded app structure, which also gets the timeout
- and yes my internet connection works just fine
- I tried the example AdIds from AdMob too, then I get the following error:

```
Error while loading ad: Error Domain=com.google.admob Code=1 
"Request Error: No ad to show." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request Error: No ad to show., gad_response_info=<GADResponseInfo: 0x6000018f4d80>}
```

I used in the 'info.plist' : `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511`
and for the AdID : `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313` both from the above mentioned tutorial pages from Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use your own appID with test Ad ID.